# Does load balancing make sense on a single hardware server?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, server

This might be a case of not actually understanding how load balancing works, but bear with me... I'm currently in the process of designing a web app, and have a single hardware server available to me. Most of the architectures I've come across use Nginx as a load balancer in front of multiple servers (with Nginx proxying to the different ports).

My question is this: I'd quite like to use Docker to containerise Nginx and a few instances of the Django application I'm going to be running (as well as the database), but is it worth having multiple instances of an application running on a single hardware server? The server can run a few instances of the Django app on different ports, but surely load balancing is about distributing the stress across hardware, in which case there would be no point?

I think a part of the confusion is the fact that 'server' can mean either hardware or software. It would be really great if someone with a better understanding could clear this up for me!

Many thanks

Comment: I had the same question before. I ran tests with this theory. I set up 3 services on docker swarm on a single node and I had it spit out the server id. I called the service from another server 1000 times. My server was a 8 core, 16 thread server. I had almost perfect even across results of load balancing. I moved it to a lower 1 core and ran the same test. Almost every request when to a single container. How large your hardware is too can determine this factor. I'm no expert at this though. Just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Docker (and public-cloud) land, there are a couple of circumstances where putting a load balancer in front of a single instance actually is useful.  The basic premise is that the load balancer's configuration is fairly stable, even if you'll be routinely restarting the underlying application, so you can point clients at the load balancer without worrying about connection details changing.

@CalumHalpin's answer hints at zero-downtime upgrades, which is one good use case.  With just plain Docker, it might work like this:

1. Start a load balancer in front of a single application container.
2. `docker build` and `docker run` a new version of the application container (with the old one still running).
3. Attach the new container to the load balancer.  Now the load balancer will serve traffic across both.
4. Detach the old container.  `docker stop` and `docker rm` it.

Now clients always connect to the load balancer, and there's no point at which there's not some backing service.  During the upgrade the load balancer has two instances and not just one.

In the various clustered environments a load balancer also gives you a way to reach a service that might be running on a different node.  A Kubernetes [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) is a load balancer with an internally visible DNS name, and combined with a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) implements the zero-downtime upgrade path described above.  In Amazon ECS you can [attach load balancers to services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html), and this used to be the best way for one service to talk to another even within the ECS cluster.

Comment: Thanks David, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective the way to know for sure which approach is better by experimentation. I can't think of any reason the multiple app instances would perform better than a single one though since you're intending to serve it with Nginx, which will already handle concurrent requests. Indeed, I would expect it to fare worse due to the containerisation overhead.

If you were worried about the stability of your application or its infrastructure then multiple instances would give you some redundancy. You could have a new instance automatically start if one fails. You could also use such a setup for zero downtime deployments using [blue-green deployments](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) or similar.

Comment: Thanks Calum. Could it be said generally then that load balancing needs to happen across multiple hardware servers to be worthwhile?

Comment: Unless you have quite a specialised use case I would say yes.